# How to access or modify dynamically created button

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created 8*8 arrays of button to create a grid for Minesweeper Game. After creating the grid I need to access them(buttons). How can I access them like change the name or disable click-ability or change the colors.

```
private void gridDesign()
{
        /***********************************Uniform grid*********************/
        int firstLoop, secondLoop;
        for (firstLoop = 0; firstLoop < 8; firstLoop++)
        {
            for (secondLoop = 0; secondLoop < 8; secondLoop++)
            {
                Button lbl = new Button()
                {
                    Name = "_" + firstLoop.ToString() +"_"+ secondLoop.ToString(),
                    Content = firstLoop.ToString() + " " + secondLoop.ToString(),
                };                   
                lbl.Click += button_Click;
                uniformgridMinesweeper.Children.Add(lbl);
            }
        }
        /********************************************************************/
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button bbb = e.Source as Button;
        bbb.Background = Brushes.Indigo;
        //how can i access a button named "_5_5"
    }
```

Comment: when you create the buttons, put them in a list. query that list for the button you want by name.

Comment: Please delete all that code and use proper WPF/XAML constructs, such as an `ItemsControl` and proper DataBinding.

Comment: BTW, please name your methods correctly, C# uses ProperCase for method names, it should be `GridDesign()` (if anything), but in fact you should completely delete all that and do this in proper XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is straightforward to access a child of a Grid with a specific property (Name):

```
 var button = uniformgridMinesweeper.Children.OfType<Button>()
    .FirstOrDefault(button => button.Name == "_5_5");
```

That said, you might want to take thumbmunkey's advice and put the buttons in your own Dictionary or lookup for quick and easy access.  Or better yet, use data binding with a view model ...